# ggplot loop deal with special characters

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Hi there I'm trying to plot a defined number of graphs using gridExtra.
This is working but unfortunately it is not dealing with special characters in its name. I tried to work around by using R friendly names and add in the actual name as a subtitle

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

Dataframe<-read.csv2(File_with_R_friendly_names.csv)

names<-read.csv2(File_with_actual_names.csv)
bar<-colnames(names)

list_of_plots<-lapply(names(Dataframe)[2:10], function(i) {
  ggplot(Dataframe, aes_string(x="X1", y=i)) + geom_point()+labs(x=i,       y="Intensity", subtitle=bar[i])
})
do.call(grid.arrange, c(list_of_plots, ncol=3))
```

If I put in `bar[2]` all graphs get the actual name but it is the same one for all while if I set bar to i, all graphs get NA.

The names I use to suit R are 
Met1, Met2, Met3, Met4, Met5, Met6, Met7, Met8, Met9 and Met10
Examples of names that I need on the plots are:

-(-)-Corey lactone
-(2R)-2,3-Dihydroxypropanoic acid
-(D-(+)-Glyceric acid?)
-1,5-Naphthalenediamine
-12-Aminododecanoic acid
-2,5-di-tert-Butylhydroquinone
-2,6-di-tert-Butylphenol
-2-Amino-N,N-diethylacetamide
-2-Ethyl-2-phenylmalonamide
-2-Naphthalenesulfonic acid

Here is the dput to reproduce the bar (names):

```
`bar<-c("X1", "(-)-Corey lactone", "(2R)-2,3-Dihydroxypropanoic acid (D-(+)-  Glyceric acid?)", "1,5-Naphthalenediamine", "12-Aminododecanoic acid", "2,5-di-  tert-Butylhydroquinone", "2,6-di-tert-Butylphenol", "2-Amino-N,N- diethylacetamide", "2-Ethyl-2-phenylmalonamide", "2-Naphthalenesulfonic acid")`
```

Here is the dput to reproduce the dataframe:

```
Dataframe<-structure(list(X1 = c(0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
Met1 = c(0, 0, 38096319.85, 45978353.93, 35077691.7, 42146132.41, 
62606961.17, 32786049.6, 51054004.82, 48898547.32), Met2 = c(0, 
0, 1288905.771, 948466.4001, 645979.6463, 1228663.251, 1137957.136, 
940928.9344, 1443680.706, 1755726.385), Met3 = c(0, 0, 575887.464, 
693692.0349, 1362477.6, 1515767.293, 2241120.502, 2417932.908, 
3866432.112, 3894701.876), Met4 = c(0, 0, 16737068.73, 21915551.3, 
12088089.1, 16003037.3, 17720785.29, 11957614.24, 13127281.5, 
14192542.13), Met5 = c(0, 0, 4556006.426, 4782909.936, 4484706.271, 
8019957.826, 5112289.476, 8537488.48, 6680688.948, 5959748.061
), Met6 = c(0, 0, 16874476.32, 15721984.25, 18093323.61, 
18619817.92, 22055835.04, 19754379.11, 29211315.88, 27321333.35
), Met7 = c(0, 0, 6604385.457, 6396794.568, 13823034.64, 
15449539.63, 26013299.82, 20262673.28, 35301685.57, 33367520.66
), Met8 = c(0, 0, 6727973.448, 7166827.569, 13238311.46, 
13986568.69, 20957194.23, 19186953.76, 34513697.47, 31192991.75
), Met9 = c(0, 0, 2373752.304, 3259738.104, 1998529.732, 
2387445.15, 2479309.442, 26924139.6, 4611277.427, 2439602.098
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), .Names = c("X1", "Met1", "Met2", "Met3", "Met4", "Met5", 
"Met6", "Met7", "Met8", "Met9"), spec = structure(list(cols =    structure(list(
X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
)), Met1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Met2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Met3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Met4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Met5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Met6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Met7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Met8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Met9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("X1", "Met1", "Met2", "Met3", 
"Met4", "Met5", "Met6", "Met7", "Met8", "Met9")), default =    structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with dput

Comment: I'm not familiar with dput usage, should i point it (x) to dataframe of list of plots?                                                                                                    'dput(x, file = "",
     control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger", "showAttributes"))'

Comment: jus do dput(Dataframe) so we can replicate the data

Comment: Cheers, for that. I have now done that and can see a file called dput in the same directory. I have done the same fr "bar" which is the names that I had to replace to plot the dataframe "DF" How to I upload it onto here?

Comment: on a sidenote: dput and other tricks to create a reproducible example are explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `names(Dataframe)[2:10]` is not number. Below will work:

```
list_of_plots<-lapply(as.numeric(names(Dataframe)[2:10]), function(i) {
ggplot(Dataframe, aes_string(x="X1", y=i)) + geom_point()+labs(x=i, 
y="Intensity", subtitle=bar[i])
})
do.call(grid.arrange, c(list_of_plots, ncol=3))
```

Comment: Hi there, I tried running and got the following warnings: `Warning message:
In lapply(as.numeric(names(Dataframe)[2:10]), function(i) { :
  NAs introduced by coercion
> do.call(grid.arrange, c(list_of_plots, ncol=3))
Warning messages:
1: Removed 10 rows containing missing values (geom_point).`
This went on til line 9:..... The plots were empty and the NA were still there as subtitle

Comment: You have to convert your colnames into numeric. If not, you can use as below: `list_of_plots<-lapply(2:10, function(i) {
  ggplot(Dataframe, aes_string(x="X1", y=i)) + geom_point()+labs(x=i, 
                                                                 y="Intensity", subtitle=bar[i])
})
do.call(grid.arrange, c(list_of_plots, ncol=3))`

Comment: That almost worked. Unfortunately the intensities are now all the same (the seem to be set to the same value at the bottome to the graph, i.e in 1st graph, they are all 2, 2nd one thare are all at 3 and so on). Thanks for your advice, this is a major improvement

Comment: In order to refer column, you can use `colnames` like below: `list_of_plots<-lapply(2:10, function(i) {
    ggplot(Dataframe, aes_string(x="X1", y=colnames(Dataframe[,i]))) + geom_point()+labs(x=i, y="Intensity", subtitle=bar[i])
})
do.call(grid.arrange, c(list_of_plots, ncol=3))`

Comment: That worked!! Its very useful as for what I'm doing, seeing the names is very important